# "Hope this will help. Thanks"

Tags: word-usage

Why some people use thanks after "Hope this will help"?

I saw "Hope this will help. Thanks" recently but I really can't understand why some people use thanks.

Here is an example; check the accepted answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22870968/wfc-rest-service-put-with-json-received-object-is-always-null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, only the person who writes *thanks* can tell you for sure why they did. So for the example added to your question you would have to ask user **Faizan Mubasher** why he said *thanks*.

However, I can give a couple possible meanings. We say *thanks* when other people do something for us. In the example added to you question, Faizan Mubasher could just be saying *thanks for providing such a good question to answer* or *thanks for allowing me to answer your question* or *thanks for using Stack Overflow*. Who knows?

In general, when communicating in English, a sincere *thanks* or *thank you* is always welcome. Except here on Stack Exchange. Since this site is meant to build up a library of unique Questions and Answers usable by anyone, personal touches such as *thanks* and *hope this helps* are judged by a high number of users to be extraneous. See

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts

and

[How helpful is it to add "Hope this is helpful!" to an ELL answer?](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1367/how-helpful-is-it-to-add-hope-this-is-helpful-to-an-ell-answer)

And while this might be true from one standpoint, it certainly makes SE seem an arid place to participate in sometimes, since the 1-on-1 connection between asker and answerer is discouraged or non-existent. While writing a good answer is deemed the best way to help the user, this ignores the human element. Other Question & Answer websites do not have such a policy.

Hope this is helpful!

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like the writer is being polite.

Since you only supplied an **excerpt**, the **thanks** probably has more to do with something communicated before this closing remark, or possibly the correspondence in general.

Possibly the writer might be extending a **thank-you** for using them as a resource.

> Hope this **will** help

sounds formal compared to the colloquial

> Hope this helps

My guess is the writer or the situation is somewhat **formal** and that's why they may have chosen to say thank-you.

Comment: the writer gave some suggestions and after that he wrote "Hope this will help. Thanks", this is why it was strange for me

Answer (score 0):

I'd have to see more context to know if this makes sense. "Hope this will help" implies that the speaker has just done something for you. "Thanks" is normally said to acknowledge that the other person has done something for him. It makes sense if there has been some exchange, i.e. A gives something to B or does something for B, B then does something in exchange for A, then B says "hope this will help", that is, the thing he gave to A, and "thanks", that is, for the thing A gave to B.

If this is a matter of A asked B for help, and then B offered some help, for B to say "thanks" wouldn't make sense.

Whether there's more going on here or the speaker just said something that doesn't really make sense in context, I can't say without knowing more of the conversation and circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

That seems like someone getting their wires crossed. They seem confused. I guess you should just interpret the "thanks" as being polite, not actually meaning anything.

Comment: _Thanks_ could mean anything. It could mean, "Thanks for asking such an interesting question." It could mean, "Thanks for being so polite in your request for help." It could just be a polite word tacked onto the end just for the sake of friendly politeness.

Comment: I think this is actually probably the correct answer.  It doesn't make much sense for the *answerer* of the question to be saying "Thanks".  I wonder if English is not his first language.